# Accessing JAX-RS RESTful API

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I'm building a `RESTful` implementation that includes both the server and some clients. The server is up and running on a cloud service.

When trying to access a resource on `JavaScript` a web client trough an `XMLHttpRequest`, I'm getting the following errors.

On Chrome:

```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://someserver.com/someresource.
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

On Firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://someserver.com/someresource. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I've read other answers recommending

```
req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

But I haven't had any luck with that.

I'm wondering if the issue has to do with some configuration that needs to be done on the server side code to allow the calls to be received and processed properly.

Could you help me solve this issue please?

Comment: Hi..Just an update! The server was reachable with no issues when the web client was modified to jQuery instead of Javascript (with no changes to the server code).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting header on request object set it on response from server side.

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
```

For Jax-RS:Implement ContainerResponseFilter

```
package com.xyz.package;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext crc) throws IOException {
      crc.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      crc.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      crc.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      crc.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      crc.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }

}
```

Comment: THank you How should I implement this on the server side? Now I'm creating the Response on server side like this:
`Response.ok(someJSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "someserver.com/").build();`

Comment: I am not sure which version you are using, for me updated answer works.

Comment: Thank you. Adding just the CORSFilter class as you have mentioned isn't helping? I've added the tomcat-catalina 7.0.42 jar and updated my web.xml by adding in 
`<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>`

And still I get the same error!